# Will dumbbell rows cause back problems?

Tags: injury-prevention, dumbbells, back-pain, lower-back, back

So we all know that dumbbell rows are good for your lats, but I am worried about the position you're in when performing them. You are bending over with a knee on the bench while pulling the weight up, and I worry if this can cause lower back pain. Is this a safe exercise for your lower back? That is my question. Thank you.

Comment: No, it would not if proper form is used.

Answer (score 1):

No, as long as you maintain proper form, it's not dangerous, the only back problems you'll have is "how can I find clothes that my huge back fit into".

Every exercise put a strain on some joint and could thus be potentially dangerous. To me, it's a lot easier to maintain a neutral back while doing dumbbell rows than during a deadlift.

Answer (score 1):

Many exercises can cause back problems if done improperly.  The [bent over row with a dumbbell](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/DBBentOverRow.html) is not an exception.   However, if done correctly, the bent over row is a good, compound exercise that strengthens multiple back, shoulder and scapular muscles.

To protect your spine:

- Keep your back slightly arched and avoid rounding your back.  Contracting your transverse abdominis (pulling your bellybutton towards your spine) will add support.
- Begin with a weight that you can control throughout the motion and avoid jerking to lift the weight.

If you have a back or disc problem, you should check with your doctor or health care practitioner first.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone said, Proper form is what is needed. If you don't maintain proper form and do warm up and cool down, there is a chance that you get injured even while walking on treadmill. So Warmup, Form, CoolDown.